# JQuery event data undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

strangerly I'm getting event.data undefined on delegate function

```
 $(".datepicker").pickadate({

        hiddenName: true,
        onOpen: function () {



            var event = ".datepicker." + this.$root[0].id;
            console.log(this);
            console.log(event);
            var data = { root: this.$root[0].id, node: this.$node[0].id };
            console.log(data);
            $(document)
                .on("scroll" + event, { root: this.$root[0].id, node: this.$node[0].id }, datePickerFun)
                .on("resize" + event, { root: this.$root[0].id, node: this.$node[0].id }, datePickerFun).scroll();
        },
        onClose: function () {

            var event = ".datepicker." + this.$root.id;
            $(document)
                .off("scroll")
                .off("resize");
        }

    });
```

and here's the delegate

```
DatePickerPositionHandler: function (e, data) {

    console.log(e.data); // undefined
    console.log(data); //undefined
    var $root = $("#" + e.data.root);
    var $node = $("#" + e.data.node);
    $root.css("top", $node.css("top") - $root.css("top"))
    $root.css("left", $node.css("left") - $root.css("left"))

},
```

The event is correctly fired but I'm not able to get the custom data I need.

Itried different sintax (for example removing the [] from the data) but the result is always the same

Any idea?

**Update**

it seems that if I'm passing static data (such {name = "a"}) it is correctly passed to the event.

even if

```
var x = this.$root[0].id;
var y = this.$node[0].id;

$(document).on("scroll" + event, { root: x, node: y }, datePickerFun)
```

the data is passed correctly.

I suppose that in moment the event fires this.$node[0].id has no meaning because of the scope.

But the solution posted works only for a single instance of the widget. As soon as I open a new instance var x, y are overwritten.

I've just noticed that th widget itself doesn't support multiple instances, so I can say assigning values to a variable will solve the issue

Comment: I don't see any connection in the code you posted between the date picker and the `DatePickerPositionHandler` function.

Comment: I've not posted the whole object. The event is actually fired, so it's not there (i suppose) the problem

Comment: don't know if it help but you should not call your variable "event" cause it is a special variable name

Comment: @Froggiz: The `event` variable is a global variable in some browsers. As long as you don't need to reference that global variable, you should be fine. jQuery event handlers are provided an `event` object as an argument. JavaScript variable scoping rules will take over and reference the argument in this case, rather than the global `event`.